# HTML - Multiple contact forms on one page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having an issue when I add two contact forms to the same page

The first contact form:

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="POST">
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date">
<input type="time" id="time" name="time">
<select name="people" id="selectEdit">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">

<input type="submit" value="Reserve table" name="reservationsubmit" class="send">
</form>
```

And this is the second form:

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="thepearlname" name="thepearlname" placeholder="Name*">
<input type="email" id="thepearlemail" name="thepearlemail" placeholder="Email*">
<textarea name="thepearlmessage" id="thepearlmessage" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send message" class="sendMessage" name="contactsubmit">
</form>
```

The first form works fine by itself, but when I add the second one neither of them will work and once I hit submit i only get the following message: 
"Error!"

And this is the content of my contact-form.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['reservationsubmit'])){
    //Reservation Form
    if (empty($_POST["date"]) || empty($_POST["time"]) || empty($_POST["people"]) || empty($_POST["name"])) {
        echo 'is empty';
    } else {
        $reserve_to = "my.mail@gmail.com";
        $reserve_subject = "New reservation";

        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $people = $_POST['people'];
        $reserve_name = $_POST['name'];

        $formcontent="Name: $reserve_name \nDate: $date \nTime: $time \nTable for: $people";

        mail($to, $subject, $formcontent) or die("Error Reservation!");

        echo "Thank you!";
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
    //Contact Form
    if (empty($_POST["thepearlname"]) || empty($_POST["thepearlemail"]) || empty($_POST["thepearlmessage"])) {
        echo 'is empty';
    } else {
        $contact_to = "my.mail@gmail.com";
        $contact_subject = "New Contact Inquiry";

        $name = $_POST['thepearlname'];
        $email = $_POST['thepearlemail'];
        $message = $_POST['thepearlmessage'];

        $contact_formcontent="Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $message";

        mail($contact_to, $contact_subject, $contact_formcontent) or die("Error Contact!");

        echo "Thank you!";


    }
} 
?>
```

Can anyone guide me into the right direction or suggest what might be causing the problem?

When I add print_r($_POST); before the the first if I'm getting the following:

```
Array ( [date] => 2015-05-28 [time] => 22:22 [people] => 3 [name] => Jane Doe [reservationsubmit] => Reserve table ) Error Reservation!
```

Comment: close your respected forms and try

Comment: From your code, if you are getting the Error message, it is because your mail() function is failing / returning an error.
Change them to or die("Error contact!"); and or die("Error reservation!"); to be able to identify which is failing.

Comment: Can't see </form> in any of the forms - did u forget to mention it ?

Comment: it is not appearing in your code, so I ask: are both forms closed with </form> ?

Comment: Also, print_r($_POST) at the top of the script before you if logic to see what is actually being passed in the POST variable.

Comment: The `</forms>` are closed properly, they just didn't survive copy/paste to stackoverflow

Comment: Post your complete error??

Comment: If error is "Error!" your mail function have error. Try mail function with four  attributes like mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: Error is generated from the `mail(...)` function call. If you are running on windows, there is no email server by default so `mail()` has nothing to pass the email onto to get it delivered. Have a look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: I've tried with 4 attributes for the mail() function but the result is the same, the site is on a hosting that has an email server, and as said, when there is only one contact form the mail gets delivered with no issues

Comment: Are you trying it localhost or live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in first if and try

```
mail($reserve_to, $reserve_subject, $formcontent) or die("Error Reservation!");
```

Comment: Thank you, the combination of four attributes and editing the first mail() function worked

Answer (score 1):

Dude,
Replace

```
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent)
```

by

```
mail($reserve_to , $reserver_subject, $formcontent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove else if and replace it with if